# How can I copy files from S3 to EFS using AWS batch?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, serverless-framework

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const BUCKET_NAME = process.env.BUCKET_NAME;
const mountLocation = '';//already defined in ecs task defination
module.exports.readEFSFile = async () => {
  //TO DO
  //Read file from mount location
  await fs.readdir(mountLocation, (err, files) => {
    files.forEach(file => {
      console.log(file);
      let filesize = calcFileSize(file);
      //considering filesize in MB
      if (filesize > 100) {
        multiUploadS3(file);
      }
      else {
        uploadToS3(file);
      }
    });
  });

};
calcFileSize = (file) => {
  //TO DO
  //return filesize in MB;
}
```

Also I have created a docker image to run this .

This is the code which I want to run on the ec2 instance where i would like to mount the filesystem which is already created.What should be the approach so that I can get the mount location .I am new to aws and I am getting confused while using ecs and ecs task defination. Serverless framework approach would be preferred if possible  .Any help would be great.Thanks in advance